# The complement of a $\sigma$- algebra

Tags: measure-theory

There is a space with measure $(X, \mathbb{F}, \mu)$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the $\sigma$ -algebra. We have two sets given:
$$\mathbb{N} = \{N \subset X: \exists F \in \mathbb{F}: \mu(F)=0 \wedge N \subset F \}$$
$$\mathbb{G} = \{F \triangle N : F \in \mathbb{F}, N \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
We are to show that:
$$\mathbb{G} = \sigma\big(\mathbb{F} \cup\mathbb{N}\big)$$
How should the proof look like? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To show equality of two sets it's often easier to show "$\subseteq$" and "$\supseteq$" separately.

So let's start with "$\supseteq$":

First consider that $\Bbb G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Then $\emptyset \in \Bbb F$ as well as $\emptyset \in \Bbb N$.

For $F \in \Bbb F$ check that  $F = F\triangle\emptyset$ hence $F \in \Bbb G$ so it follows $\Bbb F \subseteq \Bbb G$

For $N \in \Bbb N$ check that  $N = \emptyset\triangle N$ hence $N \in \Bbb G$ so it follows $\Bbb N \subseteq \Bbb G$

Because $\Bbb G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra it follows $\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N \subseteq \Bbb G$ and from that $$\sigma(\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N)\subseteq \sigma(\Bbb G) = \Bbb G$$

Now let's show "$\subseteq$":

Take $G \in \Bbb G$ then $$G = F \triangle N = (F\cup N)\setminus (F \cap N)$$ for suitable $F \in \Bbb F, N\in \Bbb N$

But because $\Bbb F,\Bbb N \subseteq \sigma(\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N)$ by definition it also holds $F,N \in \sigma(\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N)$ and $\sigma(\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra by definition hence also $$(F\cup N)\setminus (F \cap N) = G \in \sigma(\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N)$$

So it follows $$\Bbb G \subseteq \sigma(\Bbb F \cup \Bbb N)$$ and we are done.

Comment: It seems to me that the hardest part of this exercise is showing that $\Bbb G$ *is* a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Really? Found it not that hard… it's just a bit "De Morgan" - calculation… and  maybe it's good the questioner still has to do stuff on it's own :-)